# php graph is not fitting between the actual dates

Tags: php

my graph is not reading between the correct dates that the data was inserted and instead its reading the amount of rows and displaying all the 29 days. Here is the code:

```
$graphTimeOne = time();    
for($graphTimeOne = 29; $graphTimeOne >= 0; $graphTimeOne--){   
$sel_timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), date("j") - $graphTimeOne, date("Y"));  
$graphResult = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 29 DAY))");
```

Basically its suppose to display how many are per day, but instead it displays the total on every day, the interval is 29 days. Any ideas how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is incomplete - it is missing the day grouping:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM user 
WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 29 DAY))
GROUP BY DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`))
```